# Photoshop/Illustrator: Angled Dashed Line (example included)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

Hey I can create a box with a dashed line like that:
[image]
Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any options to tilt the dashes. Pls check the links for an example

[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81s%2Bodnu-hL.*SX355*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81s%2Bodnu-hL._SX355_.jpg)
http://i.ebayimg.com/images/i/152180525702-0-1/s-l1000.jpg

What's the easiest way to achieve this? I thought about masking a layer with dashes that go diagonal but that doesn't seem to be the most "dynamic" way.

SOLVED: Both are good answers and both would work for me but Scott's answer has the "dynamic" factor that I want so I marked this one. Harder to set up at first but Scott makes it easier to adjust the distance/width afterwards. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Webster's answer is a good one. A pattern brush is probably the easiest solution.

## Illustrator

Just to offer an alternative method.One *could* use a gradient applied to a stroke. This offers a little more adjustment options than a pattern brush, but it does take more effort to set up.

First create a gradient of alternating colors and hard edges. To do this, you set a color stop, then change it's position. Ultimately having 2 color stops of alternating colors in the same *position* on the gradient.

Like so.....

[image]

Notice that when the positions are adjust to be the same there's a hard edge. This particular gradient changes color every 10%, but if you want more frequent changes you can adjust for every 5% or whatever works for you. Changing the percentage after the fact is a tad cumbersome, but not difficult (actually easier to start from scratch than try and adjust what's there).

Once you have the gradient set up, just apply it to the stroke. You can then set the **angle** for the gradient to whatever you want. And increasing/decreasing the stroke weight will change the thickness of the dashes. The biggest benefit here it the ability to alter the gradient angle and thus the angle of your dashes. Pattern brushes don't really do that (not to mention the corners of pattern brushes).

[image]

Again, not as easy as a pattern brush, but sometimes more useful.

(To get a dash in the lower left AND upper right corners your gradient needs to start and stop with the same color. My gradient doesn't so it leaves the white in the lower left corner.)

Answer (score 3):

Make 1 dash, at size, solid fill the color you need.

Rotate or skew it to the right angle.

Drag your dash to the brush pallette and select "Pattern Brush", hit okay.

Draw a rectangle, select the stroke then select your dash brush.

If you don't like how it looks adjust the original dash and make another brush.

[image]